# JS: is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Ошибка только в фаерфоксе.

> ReferenceError: vislideshow is not defined.

Сам код выглядит так:

```
vislideshow();

function vislideshow(){
    $('.slide5').delay( 5000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    $('.slide4').delay( 10000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    $('.slide3').delay( 15000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    $('.slide2').delay( 20000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    vislidhide();
}
function vislidhide(){
    $('.slide2').delay( 5000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    $('.slide3').delay( 15000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    $('.slide4').delay( 20000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    $('.slide5').delay( 25000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    setTimeout(vislideshow(), 10000);
}
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Поместить вызов функции после ее определения не пробовали?

Comment: ФФ очень придирчив к порядку определений и вызовов функции. Вызывайте после определения

Comment: @Виталий, вот такой код отлично работает в FF: http://jsfiddle.net/m0bdttkc/ Похоже проблема где-то еще

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Объявление функции перенесите выше вызова, а то вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию, которую еще не объявили.

```
function vislideshow(){
    $('.slide5').delay( 5000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    $('.slide4').delay( 10000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    $('.slide3').delay( 15000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    $('.slide2').delay( 20000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    vislidhide();
}
function vislidhide(){
    $('.slide2').delay( 5000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    $('.slide3').delay( 15000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    $('.slide4').delay( 20000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    $('.slide5').delay( 25000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    setTimeout(vislideshow(), 10000);
}
vislideshow();
```

И всегда лучше выполнять JS после подгрузке всей страницы и ресурсов

```
$(function(){
    vislideshow();
});
```

Важно еще понимать принцип компиляции JS. [JIT-компиляции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIT-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Объявления функций не надо выносить наверх - это сделает парсер. Проблема точно не в этом.

Comment: JSFiddle с примером "поднятия" определения функций, который работает в FF http://jsfiddle.net/m0bdttkc/

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, да, действительно…хм

Comment: @korytoff, похоже есть еще какая-то проблема, о которой автор умолчал

Answer (score 1):

Либо перенести, либо вынести за `$(document).ready` сами функции

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    vislideshow();
});


function vislideshow(){
    $('.slide5').delay( 5000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    $('.slide4').delay( 10000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    $('.slide3').delay( 15000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    $('.slide2').delay( 20000 ).fadeOut( 5000 );
    vislidhide();
}
function vislidhide(){
    $('.slide2').delay( 5000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    $('.slide3').delay( 15000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    $('.slide4').delay( 20000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    $('.slide5').delay( 25000 ).fadeIn( 5000 );
    setTimeout(vislideshow(), 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> setTimeout(vislideshow(), 10000);
> ```

Скобки убери:

```
setTimeout(vislideshow, 10000);
```